# Export BigQuery Job API response for analysis

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there an existing service that enables export of the [Job GET Endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get) response into Biquery for analysis?

We already export and analyze [BigQuery Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs) in BQ, but those logs don't   include the query plan & other important metrics

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no service that can do this, you could fill a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685) for the BigQuery engineering team to consider having this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Until query plan stats are logged in Stackdriver (and exported to Bigquery), consider creating your own endpoint !

If your bq jobs complete within 9 min, you can write a simple Cloud Function that runs the input job config and streams the job log to SD or BQ directly.

Look at the Google Cloud Client library for the language of your choice.